# How do you make a brick texture follow a ring?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shader-nodes

I have been trying to create a circular patio with rings of bricks. I tried using the wave texture and the brick texture that come with blender, but I haven't been getting the results I wanted. Blender will use the wave, and brick information, and will only make more rings. How do I make the brick texture follow the wave texture?
I want my patio to look at least similar to the patio in this picture.

[image]

Comment: can you please add a screenshot how it should look like?

Comment: I have had this problem before. You can use UV coordinates to help correct the problem, but remember to use a Texture Coordinate node to specify the UV vector because procedural textures use generated coordinates by default (unlike image textures).

Comment: Which direction do you need your waves to go in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always go with something along these lines:

[image]

With this sort of result:

[image]

[image]

.. but I can think of all sorts of reasons not to like it.

- It curves the bricks
- You can't control the horizontal/vertical mortar thicknesses independently
- It doesn't represent the incoming curve....

and so on.

For practical purposes, would you be prepared to bake a texture from geometry?

Comment: Wooooooow!!!!!!

Comment: Actually, the result you have is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Also, mine worked better without the divide and the floor nodes.

Comment: @Grace Thanks! Okydoky, yes, those are options to keep the brick-size under control